# jquery - focusout event is firing when input gains focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `textarea` and an `input`. I am sending an ajax request when any control loses focus. I am using the following JS:

```
//Large text event
$('.custom-largetext').focusout(function () {
    getCustomCounts($(this))
});

//Autocomplete text event
$('.custom-autocomplete').focusout(function () {
    getCustomCounts($(this))
});
```

The problem I am facing is when I enter any text in the textarea and press tab, first the `focusout` of the `textarea` is firing and as soon as the `input` gains focus, its `focusout` is also getting fired. I want to do something only when any control loses its focus. Any reason why `focusout` is firing on `focusin`? I have tried with `.blur()`, but I am facing the same issue.

Any other alternative to do something when and `input` or `textarea` loses its focus?

EDIT: The `input` and `textarea` fields are added dynamically using `knockoutJS`, which why I using a common class to refer them.

**EDIT2:**

I have searched a little and the problem is with `AJAX` request being made in the `focusout` event. When I enter a value in the `input` and press tab or click on some other input control, which in both cases the focus goes to the other `input` element immediately, the AJAX request is made twice. If I click outside of the `input` the AJAX request is made only once. Any reason why this is happening? How to solve this issue?

Comment: are those dom nodes being added dynamically? if not, `blur` should work for you; otherwise you'll have to attach the event listener to an element higher up the dom tree with `.on` and specify the `blur` event.

Comment: @bruchowski yes the nodes are added dynamically using `knockout`. I tried with `.on` using both `blur` and `focusout` but still facing the same issue...

Comment: what element are you targeting? try and just do a catch all real quick with `$(document).on('blur', '.custom-largetext, .custom-autocomplete', function(){ getCustomCounts($(this)); });`

Comment: @bruchowski since the elements are added in the DOM dynamically and I wont even know the number of `textarea` or `input` elements which will be added in the DOM, I am using `css` class to target them and I am using the `ko.contextFor()` function of `knockout` to get unique id from the DOM node and I am passing this unique id and the entered value as key value pairs in the AJAX call. Tried with `$(document).on('blur'..)` as you suggested, still facing same issue....